# using mat2cell to divide a matrix of MxN into M matrix with 1xN size

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with the size of MxN, let's say 1867x3, 1867 rows and 3 columns.I I want to make it into 1867 cells with the size of 1x3.
I used mat2cell(X,[1 1866]), here X is the matrix (1867x3), the result gave two cells, one cell is the size of 1x3, the other is 1866x3. I want all the cells'(1867) size is 1x3.
I don't know if mat2cell could give me the result I want or if I should make a loop so it could happen?
Thank you,

Comment: Did you understand what your code does? For each `1` you get a vector of the size you expect, so you need 1867 ones. Try the `ones` function to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
C=mat2cell(X,ones(1,1867),[3]);
```

This command basically says to create 1867 cells of size 1 (in rows) with 3 elements each.