# Matlab: covert m x n matrix into 1 x n cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I'm new to matlab and i need helping converting the columns of a matrix into a cell. Shortly, I would like to convert an m x n matrix into a 1 x n cell. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) that converts array to cell array.

For example:

```
A=randi(10,4,3)
A =

     7     3     7
     2     1     4
     8     1    10
     1     9     1

C = mat2cell(A, size(A,1), ones(1, size(A,2)))

C = 

    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]
```

Comment: Actually it can be considered duplicate with this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542497/using-mat2cell-to-divide-a-matrix-of-mxn-into-m-matrix-with-1xn-size, just need to adjust and replace inputs order.

Comment: are you commenting to yourself?

Comment: Looks like that

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved very easily using the [num2cell function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html):

```
A = rand(10,3); % 10x3 double
B = num2cell(A,1); % 1x3 cell
```

The overload of the function that accepts two arguments allows to specify which dimensions of `A` must be included in each cell (in your case `1` for keeping the columns).

Here is the output of the code above:

```
A =
   0.397834   0.020575   0.575226
   0.634913   0.308506   0.322361
   0.093287   0.869059   0.456526
   0.105290   0.460232   0.252258
   0.593683   0.601639   0.821970
   0.688173   0.035032   0.118435
   0.152389   0.282520   0.713495
   0.903715   0.447344   0.905132
   0.773059   0.431924   0.110345
   0.932476   0.514999   0.140519

B = 
{
  [1,1] =

     0.397834
     0.634913
     0.093287
     0.105290
     0.593683
     0.688173
     0.152389
     0.903715
     0.773059
     0.932476

  [1,2] =

     0.020575
     0.308506
     0.869059
     0.460232
     0.601639
     0.035032
     0.282520
     0.447344
     0.431924
     0.514999

  [1,3] =

     0.57523
     0.32236
     0.45653
     0.25226
     0.82197
     0.11844
     0.71350
     0.90513
     0.11034
     0.14052 
}
```